# Unable to get radius of circles in d3

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create split bubble chart.In this i need to show city names on each bubble.So far I am pretty much able achieve this,there is only one problem that I am not able to get radius of the circles when I am adding text.

Here is the complete working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob7yzww6/32/)

I am adding text to circles with following code-

```
circles1.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("class", "gFontFamily")
      .style("font-size", '11px')
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.year;
      });
```

How to get radius of circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius is already a part of the data, you can get it like this:

```
circles1.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("class", "gFontFamily")
  .style("font-size", '11px')
  .text(function(d, i) {
    console.log(d.radius, d.year);
    return d.year;
  });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/qsxtq7q3/)